# I have a question on Nio's selector and threads part

Tags: java, networking, selector, nio

Please help .

When you first start the server, create a thread pool in advance (5 threads) and create 5 selectors to read, pass one selector to each Runnable, and immediately send the submit function to the thread pool.

Then, create a selector that accepts the user and run it on the main thread.

The problem here is that the Selector in the main thread detects the user's request and registers the returned SocketChannel in one of the 5 Read Selectors.

And when the connection is successful, the user sends text data every second, but there is no response from the Read Selector.

I don't know why this problem occurs.. ㅜㅜ

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Server server = new Quarter();

    }

}
```

Server.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.channels.AlreadyBoundException;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


public abstract class Server {

    protected volatile boolean isStart = true;

    // 192.168.0.11 company
    // 192.168.75.35 house
    // 192.168.75.97 my notebook
    private static final String ADDRESS = "192.168.75.35";
    private static final int    PORT    = 1111;
    private static final int    BACKLOG = 1024;

    protected Selector acceptSelector = null;

    /** 하나의 스레드에서만 접근 할것이기 때문에 동기화 처리는 필요 없음. */
    protected List<Selector> readSelectors = new ArrayList<Selector>();

    protected ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = null;
    protected InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = null;

    private final int nThreads = 5;
    protected ExecutorService threadpool = null;
    
    /** 현재 연결된 클라이언트 수 */
    protected static int connectionCount = 0;
    // volatile 캐시 메모리 문제는 아닌가?
    // 뭐가 문제지?

    protected void init() {
        try {

            this.threadpool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(this.nThreads);

            for (int i = 1; i <= this.nThreads; i++) {
                Selector sel = Selector.open();
                this.readSelectors.add(sel);
                threadpool.submit(new SubSelector(sel));
            }

            this.acceptSelector = Selector.open();
            this.inetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(ADDRESS, PORT);
            
            this.serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            
            // non - blocking 으로 설정.
            this.serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
            System.out.println("serverSocketChannel is non-blocking.");

            this.serverSocketChannel.bind(this.inetSocketAddress, BACKLOG);
            System.out.println("binding is success.");

            this.serverSocketChannel.register(this.acceptSelector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

            System.out.println("initing is success.");

        } catch (AlreadyBoundException abe) {
            // 이미 사용중인 포트에 바인딩하려면 에러
            System.err.println(abe.getMessage());
            this.exit();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            this.exit();
        }

    }

    protected synchronized void exit() {

        try {
            this.isStart = false;
            this.serverSocketChannel.close();
            this.acceptSelector.close();
            this.threadpool.shutdown();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.readSelectors.size(); i++) {
                this.readSelectors.get(i).close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.print(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
    
    protected synchronized void connectCountAdd() {
        connectionCount++;
    }
    
    protected synchronized void connectCountMinus() {
        connectionCount--;
    }
}
```

Quarter.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException;
import java.nio.channels.ClosedSelectorException;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class Quarter extends Server {

    public Quarter() {
        init();
        this.initQuarter();
    }

    private void initQuarter() {

        while (isStart) {
            try {

                int ready = acceptSelector.select();
                if (ready <= 0) continue;

                Set<SelectionKey> set = acceptSelector.selectedKeys();
                Iterator<SelectionKey> selected = set.iterator();
                
                while (selected.hasNext()) {
                    SelectionKey key = selected.next();
                    selected.remove();

                    if (!key.isValid()) continue;

                    if (key.isAcceptable()) this.accept(key);

                }
            }
            catch (ClosedSelectorException cse) {

                System.err.println(cse.getMessage());
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    private void accept(SelectionKey key) {

        try {
            ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();

            SocketChannel channel = serverChannel.accept();
            if (channel == null) return;

            channel.configureBlocking(false);

            int targetIndex = connectionCount % readSelectors.size();
            Selector tarSel = readSelectors.get(targetIndex);

            channel.register(tarSel, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

            connectCountAdd();

            System.out.println("Connected to: " + channel.getRemoteAddress());
            System.out.println("Current Connection Count: " + connectionCount);

        }
        catch (ClosedChannelException cce) {
            // 채널이 닫힌 경우
            System.err.println(cce.getMessage());
            key.cancel();
        }
        catch (ClosedSelectorException cse) {
            // 셀렉터가 닫힌 경우
            System.err.println(cse.getMessage());
            key.cancel();
            exit();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            key.cancel();
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

SubSelector.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.ClosedSelectorException;
import java.nio.channels.NotYetConnectedException;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class SubSelector extends Server implements Runnable {

   private Selector selector = null;
   Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
   
   public SubSelector(Selector selector) {
      this.selector = selector;
   }
   
   @Override
   public void run() {
      
      while (isStart) {
         
         try {
            
            int ready = selector.select();
            if (ready <= 0) return;
            
            Set<SelectionKey> set = this.selector.selectedKeys();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> selected = set.iterator();
            
            while (selected.hasNext()) {
               
               SelectionKey key = selected.next();
               selected.remove();
               
               if (!key.isValid()) continue;
               
               if (key.isReadable()) this.read(key);
            }
            
         }
         catch (ClosedSelectorException cse) {
            System.err.println(cse.getMessage());
         }
         catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
         }
      }
   }

   private void read(SelectionKey key) {
      
      try {
         
         SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
         ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);
         int readCount = channel.read(buffer);
         
         if (readCount <= 0) return;
         
         buffer.flip();
         String result = charset.decode(buffer).toString();
         
         System.out.println("client ip address: " + channel.getRemoteAddress());
         System.out.println("client send message: " + result);
      }
      catch (NotYetConnectedException nyce) {
         // 채널이 아직 연결되지 않은 경우
         System.err.println(nyce.getMessage());
      }
      catch (SocketException se) {
          System.err.println(se.getMessage());
          this.disConnect(key);
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
         // 기타 에러
         System.err.println(e.getMessage());
      }
   }
   
   private void disConnect(SelectionKey key) {
       key.cancel();
       selector.wakeup();
       connectCountMinus();
       System.out.println("Current Connection Count: " + connectionCount);
   }
}
```

Client.java

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.75.35", 1111));
            System.out.println("is Connected: " + socket.isConnected());

            while (true) {

                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                os.write(Thread.currentThread().getName().getBytes());
                os.flush();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. ㅠ.ㅠ The server is supposed to output the data sent by the client through System.out.print().

The problem is
Quarter.java

int targetIndex = connectionCount % readSelectors.size();
Selector tarSel = readSelectors.get(targetIndex);
channel.register(tarSel, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

When the server accepts the client, the client sends the data immediately. However, tarSel is still blocked at select(). ㅠ.ㅠ

Comment: ah... wakeup() and return -> continue ... modifyed Thank you bro.!